# JRuby with Swing: "The OSX menu"

Tags: java, macos, swing, jruby

I am using JRuby with the Swing library to create an OSX application. I would like to know if(and especially **how**) I can interact (add menu items etc) Application Menu in OSX.

[Here is a screenshot](http://media.tech-recipes.com/rx_images/osx/auto_hide_dock_osx.jpg). The menu I am talking about is the equivalent of where it says "Firefox" in the screenshot. Have I made myself totally clear on what I mean? :)

Regards,
Mattias

Comment: Just a note that that would be the application menu, not the Apple menu.

Comment: Thank you edited accordingly and rep'd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to pass the option on the command line:

```
java -Xdock:name=Firefox
```

Addendum: It looks like you can use [`jruby -J`](http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/JRubyCommandLineParameters) to pass the option through, although I haven't tried it.

Comment: See also [OSXAdapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/OSXAdapter/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Thank you that made it change from '/org/jruby/Main'. I had to use `jruby -J-Xdock:name=MyNewAppName`for it to work. But how can I for instance add an Preferences menu item? Is this perhaps covered in the OSXAdapter link? I just briefly scanned the webpage

Comment: I noticed that my original answer did not specify that I wanted to add menu items. I have edited so that it does. But if there is no better answer this will have to do

Comment: @maetthew: Yes, `OSXAdapter` covers that; just `unzip` and `ant run`.